# What selector to use

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a table and would like to get to the second `a` of `td` in jquery I did

```
$('td a:eq(1)').text();
```

This only gives me the the first one, but I need all `a` in all the `td`  How can I get them without using `each()`

[JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Z2Tmr/2/)

Comment: Can you reformulate your question, what do you mean by second a of td

Comment: Why don't you want to use `each`?

Comment: @Patsy Issa Second link in all table data cells

Comment: @Kamil T Seriously..?

Comment: @Youss - seriously, `each()` is designed for exactly this purpose. It's like you'd ask  "I'd like to wash my hands, how to do it without using water?" - the first question is WHY?

Comment: `var t = $('tr td:nth-child(6) a').text();` - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Dh7ca/1/

Comment: or `var t = $('tr td:nth-child(3) a').text();` - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Dh7ca/2/

Comment: @Kamil T Look at the answer ArtOfCode provided, that's how you wash..

Comment: @Youss and you could've just answered 'because I want it in elegant, CSS-like way',  instead of 'Seriously..?' ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy solution: instead of `:eq()`, use `:nth-child()`. Like this:

```
$("td a:nth-child(1)").text();
```

Here's an [updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Z2Tmr/3/).

Comment: Thanks I actually needed this `'td:nth-child(3) a'` But I figured that out based on your anwser:)

Answer (score 2):

Here is what you want http://jsfiddle.net/SS8Gt/

html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="#">1 Link 1_1</a>
            <a href="#">1 Link 1_2</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="#">1 Link 2_1</a>
            <a href="#">1 Link 2_2</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="#">1 Link 3_1</a>
            <a href="#">1 Link 3_2</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="#">2 Link 1_1</a>
            <a href="#">2 Link 1_2</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="#">2 Link 2_1</a>
            <a href="#">2 Link 2_2</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a href="#">2 Link 3_1</a>
            <a href="#">2 Link 3_2</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS

```
var a = $("table").find("td");
for(var i=0; i< a.length; i++)
{
    console.log(a.eq(i).find("a").eq(1).text());
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I was looking for a more 'elegant' (css like) way of doing this